# Updating a Field Value in a foreign DB's table in ms-Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Assume I have two Access files "Old" and "New" with the same structure. I want to Export (using SQL) a value from a field in "Old" db to its corresponding place in "New" db, initiating the SQL command from "Old" db.

To be more specific, the table name is "INFO", and the field name is "IBAN", and the exporting will be to the same ID value which is 1.

I googled and read some older questions in here, and found some similar request but with a key difference is that the order comes from "New" db, in other words, they are importing the value.

So, is what I am asking even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. set a link in OldDb that connects to table in NewDb and run an UPDATE action
2. VBA example, assuming the two files are on same computer C drive:

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE INFO IN 'C:\folder path\New.accdb' SET [IBAN]=something WHERE ID=1"`